# jQuery, remove the focus after paste with context menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, paste

I want to remove the focus on the input after paste with the context menu, here is my code:

```
// Starting with bind the paste event

$('#input').bind('paste', function(){
    // Set timeout 1 second after the paste event was run
    setTimeout(function(){
      // Here is the problem, this code does not remove the focus   
      $(this).blur();
      // Also, I try this but nothing happend
      // $('#input').blur();
    }, 1000);
});
```

By the way, the `Ctrl + V` or `Command + V` is covered with keyup keydown event. But the paste in the context menu.

You know the way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the `"this"` context is wrong.

When you run a new function inside an existing function, the this context changes.

You can save the jquery object and pass it later, for example:

```
    $('#input').bind('paste', function(){
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
    $(self).blur();
}, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in setTimeout function. `this` in setTimeout is wrong. Try this on:

```
$('#input').on('paste', function () {
    var element = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(element).blur();
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: You have a small error on the code I believe, element is already a jquery object, I'm not sure you can or should use $(element).blur, you could just use element.blur();

Comment: @Patrick you're right. You can use just `element.blur()`. But sometimes better call `$()` again. I have been stumbled few times with this strange bug before.